# How do you use a signed policy from google-cloud/storage to upload data?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, axios

> ref:
>   https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/File#getSignedPolicy

I am trying to upload files to my bucket using signed policies. Using the example from the documentation I get a response from my bucket object for 3 items.

```
"policyString": "{\"expiration\":\"2019-10-18\",\"conditions\":[[\"eq\",\"$key\",\"image.jpg\"],{\"bucket\":\"my-bucket\"},[\"eq\",\"$Content-Type\",\"image/jpeg\"],[\"content-length-range\",0,1024]]}",
"policyBase64": "[some-long-string]",
"policySignature": "[some-long-string]"
```

In the documentation it also shows you how to upload objects using curl.

> ref:
>   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#upload-object-json

How do you assemble what I get back as a signed policy and the upload api

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]

to upload a file to my bucket using axios? Is there other headers to attach?

Here is what I did to take a stab at it but I'm not sure.

```
const options = {
  headers: {
     'Authorization': ?
     'Content-Type': file.type
  }
}
axios.put(concatenatedPolicySignatureUrl, file, options)
  .then(response => {
      console.log('success!');
  }
```

Comment: how do you specify object name and location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signed policy strings only work with the XML API, which means POSTs to `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object` (and not `www.googleapis.com/upload`).

For more on exactly how to generate and use the policy, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

An example of setting up an HTTP form that would allow a user to upload an object using a policy string is below, although you could also trigger an equivalent POST request via JavaScript:

```
<form action="http://travel-maps.storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="travel-maps">
<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com">
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.example.com/success_notification.html">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTAtMDYtMTZUMTE6MTE6MTFaIiwNCiAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICJrZXkiLCAiIiBdLA0KICB7ImFjbCI6ICJidWNrZXQtb3duZXItcmVhZCIgfSwNCiAgeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidHJhdmVsLW1hcHMifSwNCiAgeyJzdWNjZXNzX2FjdGlvbl9yZWRpcmVjdCI6ICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3Nfbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLmh0bWwiIH0sDQogIFsiZXEiLCAiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciIF0sDQogIFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCAwLCAxMDAwMDAwXQ0KICBdDQp9">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="BSAMPLEaASAMPLE6SAMPLE+SAMPPLEqSAMPLEPSAMPLE+SAMPLEgSAMPLEzCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw=">

<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction @Brandon, is there examples to follow along for the JSON API?

Comment: The JSON API does not accepted signed URLs or signed policy documents. The main authorization option for it is OAuth, which is great for client libraries under your control but not a great option for serving content to others on the web (for that case, we recommend the signed URLs).

Comment: how do you specify object inside the bucket to use as upload location?

Comment: @bhavinjalodara: have the policy document require a particular name with something like `{"key" : "correctObjectName"}`. Then, have a field named "key", hidden or not, that specifies the object name.

Comment: any idea on specifying maximum upload limit. currently until policy document expires. i can upload again and again which rewrite old object. i want to make my user upload only one time for given location.

Comment: `["content-length-range", <minimum>, <maximum>]`